# Transfer events from Apache Flink to Apache NiFi - poor performance

Tags: apache-flink, apache-nifi

I integrated two tools Apache NiFi and Apache Flink. NiFi takes events and send them to Flink, after that Flink returns these events after some processing to the same NiFi.
I built source and sink to Nifi in Flink. The whole process works, but the performence of the sink is very poor (about 10 events per second).

If I remove the sink (print the output only), the process speed is much higher.

I figured out that I can change parallelism for the sink process using `setParallelism()`, of course it helps, but the base throughput is too low.
I also tried to use `requestBatchCount(1000)`, but nothing has changed.

Probably my problem is related with transactions. After each event sink wait for closing the transaction, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to change it e.g. send hundreds of events in one transaction.

What can I do for increase the performance for sink?

[image: Apache NiFi flow]

Here is my sink definition:

```
SiteToSiteClientConfig sinkConfig = new SiteToSiteClient.Builder()
    .url("http://" + host + ":" + port + "/nifi")
    .portName("Data from Flink")
    .buildConfig();

outStream.addSink(new NiFiSink<String>(sinkConfig, new NiFiDataPacketBuilder<String>() {
    public NiFiDataPacket createNiFiDataPacket(String s, RuntimeContext ctx) {
        return new StandardNiFiDataPacket(s.getBytes(), new HashMap<>());
    }
}));
```

Now I'm using the latest version of Flink (1.5.1) and NiFi (1.7.1)

Comment: You could try to batch events in the sink to reduce the number of transactions per event.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how?

Answer (score 1):

The NiFiSink provided by Apache Flink is creating a transaction for each event:

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-nifi/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/nifi/NiFiSink.java#L60-L67

It was done this way to make the error handling clear so that if the transaction fails to commit, it will throw an exception out of the invoke method in the context of the specific event that failed.

You can implement your own custom version of this that lets many events be sent before calling commit on the transaction, but I don't know enough about Flink to understand what happens if the transaction fails to commit later on and you no longer have the events.